# In C#, get a List<DerivedClass> from a List<BaseClass>

Tags: c#, derived-class

I have a Class, Food which has two derived classes: Meat and Vegetables.

If I have a List of Foods, I can get a (sub)list of Foods that are Meat using

```
List<Food> allTheFood = GetListOfFood();
List<Food> justTheMeats = allTheFood.Where(x => x is Meat);
```

But this gives me a list of type Food (where they all happen to be Meat), rather than a list of Meat.

Obviously, I could create a new empty List and then do a foreach and cast every individual item from justTheMeats from Food to Meat and add them into the new List, but that seems a convoluted approach.

Is there a nicer/easier/cleaner way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0) method.  Or you could add a `Cast<Meat>` after your `Where`.

Comment: Why do you cast it to List<Food> ? Why not
`List<Meat> justTheMeats = allTheFood.Where(x => x is Meat);`?

Comment: *I could create a new empty List and then do a foreach and cast every individual item* - curious why that was your first go-to rather than the much more obviously LINQy `Select(x => x as Meat)` on your Where?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use linq [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0)

```
var justTheMeats = allTheFood.OfType<Meat>().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I knew there'd be something simple like that, but my searches were proving fruitless.
Thanks.